# How to fix date filter showing all dates. In my date filter only showing today and after date not before

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In my code of date filter of laravel nova not showing before today date how fix it.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Nova\Filters;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Laravel\Nova\Filters\DateFilter;

class DateTo extends DateFilter
{
    /**
     * Apply the filter to the given query.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function apply(Request $request, $query, $value)
    {
        return $query->where('created_at', '<=',Carbon::parse($value));
    }
}
```

How i fix it by showing all date after and before both with my date format

[See The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru8Bo.png)

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to show both before and after the date?

What are you passing as $value?

Comment: yes, i want all date before and after but i use this code the calendar showing  only  today and after date.
in $value the value is passing by front end.

Comment: I'm still unclear. 
So if value is 01-01-2001, you want all dates before that and all dates after but not 01-01-2001?

Comment: See the Image i put it there you understand it. it's showing only today and after date.
before dates are disabled how enabled all date.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I don't think the date is disabled, it is just greyed out. You should be able to click on past date

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam No The Date which is greyed they all are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Is that date picker FlatPickr?
If so it looks like you've set a minimum date somewhere

`{
    minDate: "today"
}`

Comment: I've tried, it's quite hard to parse. 
I don't think that code is used to display your Date Picker and is what is run after you select a date. 

Can you post the code and conf for the date picker?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you then bud, I don't see how that filter code has anything to do with disabling the date picker dates.